# Jainism and Hinduism are not the same

Tags: discussion, scope

Recently a user asked a question over Jainism :-

> **Jain non-violence**
>
> Jain's are supposed to believe in nonviolence, but I don't understand
>   how that is possible. Surely, in certain circumstances you may need to
>   use force / violence but I can't find where to look for information
>   like this.
>
> I've been brought up by parents who don't believe in violence, but is
>   it against my religion to be violent at times?

So I would like to point out that Jain isn't counted in Hinduism.

Quoting from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jainism_and_Hinduism) :

> Jainism and Hinduism are two ancient Indian religions. Over the years,
>   Jainism has been influenced by Hinduism. **Jains have rejected various**
>   **Hindu deities or have incorporated them within their own system**. The
>   Jain Universal history seems to have been built around the Hindu epics
>   and traditions.

And hence, asking about Jainism will be considered as off-topic, I would like to hear comments if some users have different opinion over this...

Comment: Same should be applicable for other Indian religions: Bhuddhism, Sikhism.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jainism is similar to Hinduism in some aspects but that doesn't make it allow to be posted it here. For Budhism we have different SE, so if someone ask question on Jainism, we should redirect him/her to Area51. So that he can ask for Jainism proposal because we can't entertain Jainism question here.

*On the side note if question is on comparative aspect between Hinduism and Jainism then it should be accepted.*

Comment: Great point *If question is on comparative aspect between Hinduism and Jainism then it should be accepted.*

Comment: The reason I disagree is that Jainism will **never** have a large enough English-speaking audience to get through Area 51. And unlike other *nastika* sects, it won't belong anywhere else: Buddhism has it's own SE and Charvaka and Ajivika are on topic in Philosophy.SE. Having said that, I wouldn't expect answers here to have a neutral point-of-view toward Jainism, either. Still, at least Westerners can have the opportunity to learn some things about Jains they otherwise wouldn't. It is a difficult situation and I understand both sides, but mercy compels me to vote for allowing such questions.

Comment: If we *do* decide that Jainism is off topic here, we should at least come to agreement on where we should redirect those who ask such questions.